# Переборщить - исходное значение?

Tags: фраза

Какая тут связь с борщом? Есть ли похожие примеры?

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40796/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В словаре Даля написано, что "боршить" - означает "**лить без толку много, через край**".(to pour a lot of liquid without limit)
А по мнению П.Я.Черных (автора историко-этимологического словаря русского языка), глагол "переборщить" связан со словом "**переборчивый**" "строгий в выборе, требовательный; **привередливый**, разборчивый).(demanding, hard to please ), существительным "перебор".
Связи с «борщом», как едой нет. There's no connection with the food "borshch".

Answer (score 1):

In Russian, the word "*переборщить*" has a meaning like "*to make something more than it needs*". For example, when you are cooking a soup, you can add so much salt and in this case we can say: "*Я переборщил с солью*" (Which means "*I added so much salt*").